# Checking Hosts Value

Tags: vb.net, cmd

how to check value on "Hosts" file ?

i have host :

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1         localhost
127.0.0.1         test1
127.0.0.6         test2
127.0.0.1         test3
```

i need check "127.0.0.6 test2" on Hosts file, for server game.

code vb add new line :

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/c echo 127.0.0.6 test2 >> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts")
```

Comment: What does "check" mean? Do you just want to see if `127.0.0.6` or `test2` is in the `hosts` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is super simple using .NET

First use File.ReadAllText and String.Contains to check

Then if you need, just append with File.AppendText

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx

Example:

```
Public Class Test
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim path As String = "C:\Windows\ System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts"

    If File.Exists(path) AndAlso Not File.ReadAllText(path).Contains(“127.0.0.6 test2”) Then

        ‘File exists and doesn’t have our string - let’s add it
        Dim appendText As String = "This is extra text" + Environment.NewLine
    File.AppendAllText(path, appendText)

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class